# Is it possible to have a property sensor detect another property?

Tags: game-engine, properties

Is it possible to have a property sensor detect another property?

Like this:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have a property sensor detect another property?

(I assume you want to compare on property's value with another property's value.)

No, the property sensor evaluates a single property only.

When you want to evaluate more properties you can use the expression controller:

```
property_1 < property_2
```

or the Python controller

```
import bge 

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner
if owner["property_1"] < owner["property_2"]:
    for actuator in controller.actuators:
        controller.activate(actuator)
else:
    for actuator in controller.actuators:
        controller.deactivate(actuator)
```

I hope this helps